# How to link the json file in c# console?

Tags: c#, json, configuration, json.net

I'm new to C# and don't have the knowledge of json format. I wrote a c# script with c# console to extract some of the information from an `mht` file in a folder. But currently the input path is hardcoded inside.

I would like to know how to write the path a in json file and read that in C#. My colleagues tell me to search for an available package on NuGet, I'm not sure can use *Newtonsoft.Json* or not. I have searched for other similar questions on Stackoverflow but still don't understand how to write it.

Cuurently in my c# script i read the file path like this:

```
DirectoryInfo mht_file = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\liewm\Desktop\data\");
```

The reason why I need to make it read from a json file because after building the project we can just simply change the file path in the json file easily.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is **Configuration / `appsettings.json`**.

**I assume you are using .NET Core** because you are talking about JSON config files. If so, you can take a look at this tutorial: https://blog.bitscry.com/2017/05/30/appsettings-json-in-net-core-console-app/

For .NET Framework apps, you can use the app.config XML, or parse the JSON by hand (*) if you absolutely need the json format.

EDIT: In theory you can parse the JSON yourself using *Newtonsoft.Json* if you want, however for most needs using the built in config parser does the job perfectly.